# Error during implementation of quickSort algorithm in c++:- "error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**'....."

Tags: c++, quicksort

The full error is as follows:- "|error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void quickSort(int**, int, int)'|"

MY whole code is below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Partition (int *A[], int p, int r) {
    int x = *A[r];
    int i = p-1;
    for (int j=0; j<=r; j++){
        if(*A[j]<=x){
            i++;
            int save=*A[j];
            *A[j] = *A[i];
            *A[i] = save;
        }
    }
    int save2=*A[i+1];
    *A[i+1]=*A[r];
    *A[r]=save2;
    return (i+1);
}

void quickSort(int *A[], int p, int r) {
    if (p<r){
    int q = Partition(A, p, r);
    quickSort(A, p, (q-1));
    quickSort(A, (q+1), r);
    }
}



int main() {
    int RR[] = {2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4};
    int y=sizeof(RR)/sizeof(int)-1;
    cout << y << endl;
    int *QQ = RR;
    cout << *QQ << endl;
    quickSort(QQ, 0, y);

    return 0;
}
```

This is an implementation that I tried myself from a pseudo code. I'm new to programming so it would be a great help if you could illustrate a little of why this error occurred.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `int *A[]` vs `int *QQ`: missing one dimension. just read the compiler error message.

Comment: Alternative: Rewrite your functions so that they don't require a pointer to the array. You don't need to use a pointer here.

Comment: The declaration `int *A[]` is for an *array of pointers* to integers.  The declaration `int A[]` is an array of integers.  Are you passing an array of integer or pointers?

Comment: @user4581301  I tried re-writing the functions as so it compute with directly passing the array in it instead of pointers. Though the errors went away, the program crashed when i ran it. Also, won't declaring new arrays in each function increase the use of memory as supposed to using pointers.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I think I understand it, I tried using int *A instead of int*A[]. But same as before though the errors went away but it still crashed.

I'm pretty bad this ain't I.

Comment: @VibhuDubey the program crashes because of a logic error in the `Partition` function. Step through `Partition` a few times with your development environment's debugger and you'll see the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 you were right, i found that error in the comparison operator of the Partition. Thank you man !~vibster

Comment: To pass an array by reference, you can use `template<size_t N> void quicksort(int (&A)[N], int p, int r)`.  This may prove more useful than pointers, since I don't see any pointer arithmetic in there.  Additionally, since `r` is the last (`(sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0])) - 1`th) element, and `N` is the size of the array, you can then make `r` default to `N - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice about the code is a whole lot of unneccessary pointer dereferencing. The contents of `A` will be changed without the need for additional pointers because Arrays decay to pointers ([What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)) so `A` is treated as a pointer to the first array element and you are effectively passing the array by reference already.

Worse, `int * A[]` isn't a pointer to an array of `int`, it is an array of pointers to `int`. A very different thing. `*A[0]` does not return 2, it tries to use 2 as an address and return whatever happens to be in memory at address 2. This will almost certainly not be anything you want, or are allowed, to see so the program will do something unfortunate. Crash if you are lucky.

Instead, try

```
int Partition (int A[], int p, int r) {
    int x = A[r];
    int i = p-1;
    for (int j=0; j<=r; j++){
        if(A[j]<=x){
            i++;
            int save=A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = save;
        }
    }
    int save2=A[i+1];
    A[i+1]=A[r];
    A[r]=save2;
    return (i+1);
}

void quickSort(int A[], int p, int r) {
    cout << p << ',' << r << endl; // Bonus: This will make the next bug really easy to see
    if (p<r){
    int q = Partition(A, p, r);
    quickSort(A, p, (q-1));
    quickSort(A, (q+1), r);
    }
}
```

Note the extra `cout` statement at the top of `quickSort` This will help you see the logic error in `Partition`. The program will crash due to a... wait for it! A Stack Overflow, but the `cout` will show you why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially for the tip, Now back to fixing that Recursion. Thanks Again!

Comment: @VibhuDubey Another hint: the [Wikipedia page for Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) about 1/4 of the way down has a pseudocode for Lomuto Quicksort, which I'm pretty sure is what you're implementing. If you compare what you have against what they have you should have the bugs picked off in a few minutes. I count 5 differences/bugs. That said, I've always found the Hoare version harder to get wrong.